# Make the pause button perform only once

Tags: python, pygame

```
import sys
import math
import random
import pygame
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from io import BytesIO

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Constants for the game window
WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
WINDOW_TITLE = "Zombie Survival Game"

# Constants for the player
PLAYER_WIDTH = 64
PLAYER_HEIGHT = 36
PLAYER_INITIAL_X = (WINDOW_WIDTH - PLAYER_WIDTH) // 2
PLAYER_INITIAL_Y = WINDOW_HEIGHT - PLAYER_HEIGHT - 10

# Constants for the bullet
BULLET_SIZE = 10
BULLET_RADIUS = BULLET_SIZE // 2
BULLET_SPEED = 10

# Customizations
BASE_PLAYER_SPEED = 3  # Base speed of the player
RECOIL = 10  # Recoil caused by each bullet
GUN_TIP_OFFSET = 5  # Offset from the center to the tip of the gun
BULLET_FIRE_RATE = 15  # Time between each bullet (in frames)
DASH_COOLDOWN = 60  # Cooldown for the dash in frames

# Modify the apply_bullet_knockback function to call update_player_money when a zombie dies
def apply_bullet_knockback(zombie, angle, knockback_distance):
    zombie[0] += knockback_distance * math.cos(angle)
    zombie[1] += knockback_distance * math.sin(angle)
    
    # Check if the zombie is dead (health <= 0)
    if zombie[2] <= 0:
        update_player_money(zombie[6])  # Pass the zombie damage to update player money

# Modify the update_player_money function to properly update player money
def update_player_money(zombie_damage):
    global player_money
    # Define the money value for each zombie damage
    zombie_money_values = {
        10: 5,  # Example: 10 damage zombie gives 5 money
        20: 30,  # Adjust these values based on your game's balance
        5: 10,
        30: 250
    }
   
    # Check if the zombie damage is valid
    if zombie_damage in zombie_money_values:
        player_money += zombie_money_values[zombie_damage]

# Function to display damage indicator on a zombie
def display_damage_indicator(zombie_x, zombie_y, damage, zombie_size):
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    text = font.render("-" + str(damage), True, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text, (zombie_x + zombie_size[0] // 4, zombie_y - 10))  # Adjusted position for damage indicator

# Constants for colors
LIGHT_GREY = (200, 200, 200)

# Add a new variable to track the change in brightness
brightness_change = 0

# Load player image
player_image = pygame.image.load('player.svg')  # Make sure the path is correct
player_image = pygame.transform.scale(player_image, (PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT))

# Load different zombie images and their attributes
zombie_attributes = {
    "normal": {"image": pygame.image.load('zombie_normal.svg'), "size": (PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT),
               "health": 50, "speed": 2, "damage": 10},
    "strong": {"image": pygame.image.load('zombie_strong.svg'), "size": (PLAYER_WIDTH + 20, PLAYER_HEIGHT + 20),
               "health": 100, "speed": 1, "damage": 20},
    "fast": {"image": pygame.image.load('zombie_fast.svg'), "size": (PLAYER_WIDTH - 20, PLAYER_HEIGHT - 20),
             "health": 30, "speed": 3, "damage": 5},
    "boss": {"image": pygame.image.load('zombie_boss.svg'), "size": (PLAYER_WIDTH + 50, PLAYER_HEIGHT + 50),
             "health": 200, "speed": 0.5, "damage": 30}
}

# Change bullet properties
BULLET_RADIUS = BULLET_SIZE // 2

# Bullet list to store active bullets
bullets = []

# List to store zombie attributes [x, y, health, speed, image, size, damage]
zombies = []

# Variable to track whether the game is paused
game_paused = False

# Initialize bullet fire timer
bullet_fire_timer = 0

# Constants for health and damage
PLAYER_INITIAL_HEALTH = 100
BULLET_DAMAGE = 5

# Add a global variable for bullet knockback distance
BULLET_KNOCKBACK_DISTANCE = 5  # Adjust this value as needed

# Initialize player attributes
player_x = PLAYER_INITIAL_X
player_y = PLAYER_INITIAL_Y
player_health = PLAYER_INITIAL_HEALTH

# Initialize player money
player_money = 0

# Load the higher-resolution shop image
shop_image = pygame.image.load("shop.svg")
shop_image = pygame.transform.scale(shop_image, (600, 600))  # Adjust size as needed

# Adjust the shop position to the right
shop_x = (WINDOW_WIDTH - shop_image.get_width()) // 2 + 50  # Shifted 50 pixels to the right
shop_y = (WINDOW_HEIGHT - shop_image.get_height()) // 2

# Variables for shop animation
shop_y = WINDOW_HEIGHT  # Starting position off-screen
shop_target_y = (WINDOW_HEIGHT - 600) // 2  # Target position at the center of the screen
shop_speed = 10  # Speed of the shop animation

# Variable to track whether the shop is currently displayed
shop_displayed = False

# Add a new variable to track if the shop is currently moving
shop_moving = False

# Create the game window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption(WINDOW_TITLE)

# Dictionary to store zombie type percentages
ZOMBIE_PERCENTAGES = {}

# Function to spawn a random zombie based on percentages
def spawn_random_zombie():
    global zombie_spawn_timer

    if not ZOMBIE_PERCENTAGES:
        return

    total_percentage = sum(ZOMBIE_PERCENTAGES.values())
    rand_num = random.randint(1, total_percentage)
    cumulative_percentage = 0

    for zombie_type, percentage in ZOMBIE_PERCENTAGES.items():
        cumulative_percentage += percentage
        if rand_num <= cumulative_percentage:
            attributes = zombie_attributes[zombie_type]
            spawn_zombie(zombie_type, attributes)
            break

# Function to modify the spawn rate
def modify_spawn_rate(spawn_rate_change):
    global ZOMBIE_SPAWN_INTERVAL
    ZOMBIE_SPAWN_INTERVAL = max(1, ZOMBIE_SPAWN_INTERVAL + spawn_rate_change)  # Ensure it's at least 1

# Initialize zombie spawn interval
ZOMBIE_SPAWN_INTERVAL = 250  # Increase this value to reduce spawn rate
zombie_spawn_timer = 0  # Initialize zombie spawn timer

# Modify zombie spawn rate
modify_spawn_rate(-10)  # Call after defining ZOMBIE_SPAWN_INTERVAL

# Function to modify zombie percentages
def modify_zombie_percentages(zombie_type, new_percentage):
    global ZOMBIE_PERCENTAGES
    new_percentage = max(0.0, min(100.0, float(new_percentage)))  # Ensure percentage is in valid range
    ZOMBIE_PERCENTAGES[zombie_type] = new_percentage

# Modify zombie percentages (adjust as needed)
modify_zombie_percentages("normal", 100.0)
modify_zombie_percentages("strong", 80.0)
modify_zombie_percentages("fast", 60.0)
modify_zombie_percentages("boss", 15.0)

# Function to move zombies towards the player
def move_zombies_towards_player():
    for zombie in zombies:
        if zombie[2] <= 0:
            # Zombie is dead, don't move it
            continue

        # Calculate the angle between the zombie and the player
        angle = math.atan2(player_y - zombie[1], player_x - zombie[0])

        # Move the zombie towards the player
        zombie[0] += math.cos(angle) * zombie[3]  # Update x position
        zombie[1] += math.sin(angle) * zombie[3]  # Update y position

# Function to handle player being hit by a zombie
def player_hit_by_zombie():
    global player_health
    global invincible_timer
    if invincible_timer <= 0:
        # Check collision with zombies
        player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_x, player_y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT)
        zombie_dealt_damage = False  # Track if a zombie has dealt damage

        for zombie in zombies:
            if zombie[2] <= 0:
                # Zombie is dead, skip
                continue
            zombie_rect = pygame.Rect(zombie[0], zombie[1], zombie[5][0], zombie[5][1])

            if player_rect.colliderect(zombie_rect):
                # Reduce player health if a zombie is in contact
                if not zombie_dealt_damage:
                    player_health -= zombie[6]
                    invincible_timer = 5 * 60  # 5 seconds at 60 FPS
                    zombie_dealt_damage = True

# Timer to control dash animation
dash_timer = 0
DASH_DURATION = 10
dash_cooldown = 0

# Function to handle player dash
def player_dash():
    global player_x, player_y, dash_timer, dash_cooldown

    if dash_cooldown <= 0 and dash_timer > 0:
        dash_distance = 10
        angle_deg = math.degrees(dash_angle)
        if 180 <= angle_deg <= 360:
            # Adjust the angle for dashing up
            player_x -= dash_distance * math.cos(dash_angle)
            player_y -= dash_distance * math.sin(dash_angle)
        else:
            # Adjust the angle for dashing down
            player_x += dash_distance * math.cos(dash_angle)
            player_y += dash_distance * math.sin(dash_angle)
        # Limit the player position within the window
        player_x = max(0, min(player_x, WINDOW_WIDTH - PLAYER_WIDTH))
        player_y = max(0, min(player_y, WINDOW_HEIGHT - PLAYER_HEIGHT))
        dash_timer -= 1
        if dash_timer == 0:
            dash_cooldown = DASH_COOLDOWN

# Function to check if a point is inside a rectangle
def is_point_inside_rect(point_x, point_y, rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height):
    return rect_x <= point_x <= rect_x + rect_width and rect_y <= point_y <= rect_y + rect_height

# Function to spawn a specific type of zombie
def spawn_zombie(zombie_type, attributes):
    # Randomly spawn the zombie off-screen
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        zombie_x = random.choice([-attributes["size"][0], WINDOW_WIDTH])
        zombie_y = random.randint(0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - attributes["size"][1])
    else:
        zombie_x = random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH - attributes["size"][0])
        zombie_y = random.choice([-attributes["size"][1], WINDOW_HEIGHT])

    zombies.append([zombie_x, zombie_y, attributes["health"], attributes["speed"],
                    attributes["image"], attributes["size"], attributes["damage"]])
    
# Add a new variable to track if the shop is currently moving
shop_moving = False

# Main game loop
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Game over font
game_over_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 100)

# Initialize invincibility timer
invincible_timer = 0

# Initialize zombie spawn timer
zombie_spawn_timer = 0

# Stamina bar constants
MAX_STAMINA = 200
STAMINA_REGEN_RATE = 1  # Stamina regenerated per frame when not sprinting
STAMINA_DEPLETION_RATE = 2  # Stamina depleted per frame when sprinting
STAMINA_DASH_COST = 50  # Stamina cost for dashing
stamina = MAX_STAMINA  # Initial stamina

# Add this variable to ignore 'P' key during shop animation
ignore_p_key = False

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
    # Check if the game is paused
    if not game_paused:
        # Clear the screen with light grey
        screen.fill(LIGHT_GREY)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # Get the mouse position
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    
        # Update zombie spawn timer and spawn zombies
        zombie_spawn_timer -= 1
        if zombie_spawn_timer <= 0:
            spawn_random_zombie()
            zombie_spawn_timer = ZOMBIE_SPAWN_INTERVAL

        # Calculate the angle between the player and the cursor
        angle = math.atan2(mouse_y - (player_y + PLAYER_HEIGHT / 2), mouse_x - (player_x + PLAYER_WIDTH / 2))
        angle = math.degrees(angle)

        # Rotate the player image
        rotated_player = pygame.transform.rotate(player_image, -angle)
        rotated_rect = rotated_player.get_rect(center=(player_x + PLAYER_WIDTH / 2, player_y + PLAYER_HEIGHT / 2))

        # Get the keys pressed (WASD for movement)
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            player_x -= BASE_PLAYER_SPEED
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            player_x += BASE_PLAYER_SPEED
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            player_y -= BASE_PLAYER_SPEED
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            player_y += BASE_PLAYER_SPEED

        # Limit the player position within the window
        player_x = max(0, min(player_x, WINDOW_WIDTH - PLAYER_WIDTH))
        player_y = max(0, min(player_y, WINDOW_HEIGHT - PLAYER_HEIGHT))

        # Dash mechanic
        global dash_angle
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and stamina >= STAMINA_DASH_COST and dash_cooldown <= 0:
            # Dash towards the cursor
            dash_angle = math.atan2(mouse_y - (player_y + PLAYER_HEIGHT / 2), mouse_x - (player_x + PLAYER_WIDTH / 2))
            dash_timer = DASH_DURATION
            stamina -= STAMINA_DASH_COST
        else:
            # Regenerate stamina if not dashing
            stamina = min(MAX_STAMINA, stamina + STAMINA_REGEN_RATE)

        # Update cooldowns
        if dash_cooldown > 0:
            dash_cooldown -= 1

        # Update and draw bullets
        new_bullets = []
        for bullet in bullets:
            bullet[0] += math.cos(math.radians(bullet[2])) * BULLET_SPEED
            bullet[1] += math.sin(math.radians(bullet[2])) * BULLET_SPEED

            # Check if bullet is off-screen or hits a zombie
            bullet_rect = pygame.Rect(bullet[0] - BULLET_RADIUS, bullet[1] - BULLET_RADIUS, BULLET_SIZE, BULLET_SIZE)
            bullet_hit_zombie = False

            for zombie in zombies:
                if zombie[2] <= 0:
                    # Zombie is dead, skip
                    continue

                zombie_rect = pygame.Rect(zombie[0], zombie[1], zombie[5][0], zombie[5][1])

                if bullet_rect.colliderect(zombie_rect):
                    # Reduce zombie health
                    zombie[2] -= BULLET_DAMAGE
                    if zombie[2] <= 0:
                        zombies.remove(zombie)
                    bullet_hit_zombie = True

                    # Apply knockback to zombie
                    apply_bullet_knockback(zombie, math.radians(bullet[2]), RECOIL)
                
                    # Display damage indicator on zombie
                    display_damage_indicator(bullet[0], bullet[1], BULLET_DAMAGE, (BULLET_SIZE, BULLET_SIZE))

            if not bullet_hit_zombie and 0 <= bullet[0] < WINDOW_WIDTH and 0 <= bullet[1] < WINDOW_HEIGHT:
                # Draw the bullet image only if it didn't hit a zombie and is on-screen
                bullet_image = pygame.image.load('bullet.svg')  # Make sure the path is correct
                bullet_image = pygame.transform.scale(bullet_image, (BULLET_SIZE, BULLET_SIZE))
                screen.blit(bullet_image, (bullet[0] - BULLET_RADIUS, bullet[1] - BULLET_RADIUS))
   
            # Remove bullets that are off-screen or hit a zombie
            if 0 <= bullet[0] < WINDOW_WIDTH and 0 <= bullet[1] < WINDOW_HEIGHT and not bullet_hit_zombie:
                new_bullets.append(bullet)
        bullets = new_bullets

        # Fire bullets based on the fire rate
        bullet_fire_timer += 1
        if bullet_fire_timer >= BULLET_FIRE_RATE:
            mouse_click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            if mouse_click[0] == 1:
                # Fire a bullet from the tip of the gun
                bullet_x = player_x + PLAYER_WIDTH / 2 + GUN_TIP_OFFSET * math.cos(math.radians(-angle))
                bullet_y = player_y + PLAYER_HEIGHT / 2 + GUN_TIP_OFFSET * math.sin(math.radians(-angle))
                bullets.append([bullet_x, bullet_y, angle])
                bullet_fire_timer = 0

        # Move zombies towards the player
        move_zombies_towards_player()
    
        # Check if the "p" key is pressed to toggle the shop display
        if keys[pygame.K_p] and not shop_moving:  # Only toggle when shop is not moving
            shop_moving = True
            shop_displayed = not shop_displayed
            shop_speed = -shop_speed if shop_displayed else shop_speed

        # Update the shop animation
        if shop_moving:
            if shop_displayed:
                if shop_y > shop_target_y:
                    shop_y -= shop_speed
                    if shop_y <= shop_target_y:
                        shop_y = shop_target_y
                        shop_moving = False  # Stop the shop movement
            else:
                if shop_y < WINDOW_HEIGHT:
                    shop_y += shop_speed
                    if shop_y >= WINDOW_HEIGHT:
                        shop_y = WINDOW_HEIGHT
                        shop_moving = False  # Stop the shop movement

        # Update and draw zombies
        for zombie in zombies:
            if zombie[2] <= 0:
                # Zombie is dead, don't add it to the new zombie list
                continue

            # Calculate the angle between the zombie and the player
            angle = math.atan2(player_y - zombie[1], player_x - zombie[0])
            angle = math.degrees(angle)

            # Rotate the zombie image
            rotated_zombie = pygame.transform.rotate(zombie[4], -angle)
            zombie_rect = rotated_zombie.get_rect(center=(zombie[0] + zombie[5][0] / 2, zombie[1] + zombie[5][1] / 2))

            # Draw the rotated zombie
            screen.blit(rotated_zombie, zombie_rect.topleft)

        # Check if player is hit by a zombie
        player_hit_by_zombie()

        # Display player health
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
        text = font.render("Player Health: {}".format(player_health), True, (255, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(text, (10, 10))

        # Display stamina bar
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (10, 50, stamina, 20))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (10 + stamina, 50, MAX_STAMINA - stamina, 20))
    
        # Display player money
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
        money_text = font.render("Money: ${}".format(player_money), True, (0, 0, 255))
        screen.blit(money_text, (10, 80))
    
        # Draw the player
        screen.blit(rotated_player, rotated_rect.topleft)
    
    # Draw the higher-resolution shop icon
    screen.blit(shop_image, (shop_x, shop_y))
    if shop_moving or shop_displayed:
        # Update the shop position based on the movement speed
        shop_y += shop_speed
        # Check if the shop has reached its target position or gone off-screen
        if shop_speed > 0 and shop_y >= WINDOW_HEIGHT:
            shop_y = WINDOW_HEIGHT
            shop_moving = False  # Stop the shop movement
        elif shop_speed < 0 and shop_y <= shop_target_y:
            shop_y = shop_target_y
            shop_moving = False  # Stop the shop movement

    # Check if the game is paused and adjust brightness
    if game_paused:
        # Create a transparent surface to darken the screen
        darken_surface = pygame.Surface((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        darken_surface.fill((35, 35, 35, 35))  # Adjust alpha for desired darkness
        screen.blit(darken_surface, (0, 0))

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

    # Check for key presses to toggle pause
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_p]:
        # Toggle the game pause state and handle game state accordingly
        game_paused = not game_paused

    # Check if player is alive
    if player_health <= 0:
        # If the game is paused, start the 3-second timer
        if game_paused:
            game_over_timer = 3 * 60  # 3 seconds at 60 FPS
        else:
            # Restart the game after 3 seconds
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.time.wait(3000)

            # Reset game
            bullets = []
            zombies = []
            player_health = PLAYER_INITIAL_HEALTH
            player_x = PLAYER_INITIAL_X
            player_y = PLAYER_INITIAL_Y
            stamina = MAX_STAMINA
            invincible_timer = 0
            zombie_spawn_timer = 0
            bullet_fire_timer = 0

    # Update the invincibility timer
    if invincible_timer > 0:
        invincible_timer -= 1

    # Handle player dash
    player_dash()
    
    zombie_spawn_timer -= 1

# Quit Pygame and close the window when the game loop ends
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

In the above code I want it so that during the shop animation I don't any "p" key being pressed and when the shop comes in the middle and then when we press "p" the shop leaves and during the animation of the shop leaving ignore any "p" key being pressed. The issue is that I can hold the p button and the game is just pausing the game back and forth and shop comes in slow motion. The main objective is that the player when he presses the "P" button the shop comes up and make the game pause behind so that the player can buy items and after he is done buying he can press the "P" button again to play again. If also possible make a timer like after when the player leaves the shop a 3 second timer will show up on screen and resume the game just to make the player see his surroundings. Please I need the answer quick I have to submit this code for a competition.

I tried multiple ways but it don't work

Comment: You're checking for the 'p' key several times here.  What you need is another flag that says "animation is in progress", and do not allow the game to unpause until that clears.

Comment: Pls post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). People won’t read lots of code to solve your problems

Answer (score -1):

You are checking the P key multiple times.
You will need to also check your store flag when checking for p here:

```py
# Check for key presses to toggle pause
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_p]:
```

So something like:

```py
if keys[pygame.K_p] and not shop_displayed:
```